# Errors while upgrading to d3js version 5

Tags: d3.js

I just recently tried switching to d3 v5 from v4, and I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) errors every place I use d3.json.  I cannot seem to figure out what changed or if this is a bug.

Here is a typical call to a random data set in v4, which works perfectly fine with the v4 library:

```
var url = "somedata.json";
d3.json(url, function(error, json) { console.log(json); });
```

I changed the code appropriately for v5 and get a 401 error:

```
var url = "somedata.json";
d3.json(url).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });
```

My apologies if I did not make it clear initially that the problem is the 401 error.  Apart from the promise construct, the only change was the d3 version.

I created a plunk for this and it works just fine:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iTZzdc27eJaubiOJvmsi?p=preview

I am thinking the problem is a combination of the d3 v5 library with my web server (which is on a private network): IIS using Windows domain security.  Since version 4 (and all previous versions) have worked great, I am thinking either something changed with d3, or I need to do something more in the request.

Comment: Is your JSON API protected in some way?  Perhaps by a cookie?

Comment: @gerardofurtado, I re-opened this one, looks like there's more to it then not just understanding the fetch/promise change with d3 v5.

Comment: @Mark yes, you're correct,, I missed the *"I also tried..."* part.

Comment: I do not think my JSON API is protected.  How would I know?  The difference appears to be that d3 in v5 is now a wrapper around the Fetch API and I suppose since my web server requires authentication, I had to put something in there to override indications of anonymity.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to add credential information to the request:

```
var url = "somedata.json";
d3.json(url, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .then(function(data) { console.log(data); });
    .error(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

This explains the issue:
[Access denied under Basic Authentication](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/issues/16)

Answer (score -1):

Typical usage of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) is done the following way:

```
doSomething().then(function(response) {
   // success
}).catch(function(error) {
   // error
});
```

Hence `d3.json()` will result in the following structure:

```
d3.json(url).then(function(json) {
   console.log(json);
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

I've created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) using the same:

[DEMO FOR d3 v5 Promises (d3.json() example)](http://plnkr.co/edit/nsvBNW5UFXmEZlKc0mCm?p=preview)

For testing purposes, try changing the **URL** in the `d3.json()` function and you'll observe the error in the console.

Read more about promises [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/introduction-to-promises). Also, please go through the documentation for [d3 v5 - CHANGES](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gerardo Thanks. I never checked for a duplicate. My bad. Anyway, hope the example (plunkr) is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that was the first thing I saw when I got the 401 error and tried, but still got a 401 error which is my real issue.  I tried the other data fetch methods, such as d3.csv and get the same error.

Comment: @Shashank No worries. At the end this was not a duplicate, OP already  stated in his question that he tried the promise pattern (that's probably why you've got a downvote).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado At the time when the question was posted, the OP hadn't mentioned the fact that he tried the promise pattern and so I came up with this. (the downvoter mustn't have considered this). Anyway, I just read the edited question. Michael: would you mind creating a plunkr reproducing the issue? If you say it works with v4 and not with v5, that makes it something to look into.

Comment: @Shashank if you look at the edit history it's there, in the first version. It was my mistake missing that and closing it as a duplicate

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If you look at the first version, the promise's `then` callback has 2 arguments `function(error, json)` which is not correct, is it? And so I came up with the typical usage of promises and how to catch an error (if any).

Comment: Anyway, I think it's something related to accessibility (credentials) to the file. It's better to have a `catch` callback to check the error in detail.